# R, How do I use here() within parse()

Tags: r

I know how much you love the here() package... I'm just starting to catching on.

I am trying to write an (relatively) automated code for cleaning data and I would like to use here() and parse(). But parse() doesn't seem to like having here() within it.

```
cleaning <- parse(file = here("folder", "source-code.R"))
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in here("folder", "source-code.R"):
  unused argument ("source-code.R")
```

If I set my working directory as the folder containing "source-code.R" and remove the here() argument, the process works just fine.

also, I've tried removing the "folder" and just calling the "source-code.R", but then I get the error:

```
Error in parse(file = here("source-code.R")) :
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `conflicts()` show anything for `here()`? Or what does `environment(here)` return? Sounds like you might be running into a naming conflict. Did you load `plyr` or something?

Comment: that is the issue!
I did have `plyr` loaded. I tried opening it up in a clean environment and only loading `here` and it worked just fine.

Can you tell me more about the issue?
`environment(here)` returned `<environment: namespace:plyr>`
and `conflicts()` returns a list of 19 results, with `here` being one of them.

Do you resolve these conflicts by using the syntax `here::here()`?

Comment: yes you can!  `here::here()` worked just fine.  I'm starting to catch on. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Use `here::here()`That would be the safest way to make sure you are using the correct functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MrFlick who recognized the naming conflict. Using `here::here()` solved it!